How can I retrieve the content of my streamlit application cache?
In Streamlit 1.35.0, there are useful functions that allows one to keep data in memory. Data is stored in application cache and this avoids having to upload the data every time a modification is made in the rest of the code.
There are two functions like this in Streamlit:

cache_data (https://docs.streamlit.io/develop/api-reference/caching-and-state/st.cache_data)
cache_resource (https://docs.streamlit.io/develop/api-reference/caching-and-state/st.cache_resource)

In my application, I would like to add a button "Raise a bug" that will create a semi-filled email with attachments. I would like the attachments to be what is stored in the cache. In my case I am interested by the user inputs.
Is there an easy and native way to retrieve what is stored in the cache using Streamlit ?
